# Add search query request header onto curled URL

Tags: php

I am trying to add a request header that is generated when a user searches an airport code in the form using weather.com. I have successfully requested the first page, but I need help figuring out how I can add a search query string on the end of my current URL.

The query string is `search?where=phx&start_with=1&search_loc_type=9&x=5&y=13`. The `phx` is the airport code.

I am trying to figure out how to add this query string, for example, `search?where="Airport_variable".&start_with=1&search_loc_type=9&x=5&y=13`.

So when a person types a airport code its fetched by the weather.com server and added to the search query and displaying the search results based on that query*h*e.

Can someone please help me?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
   $URL = "http://www.weather.com/activities/travel/businesstraveler/";   
   $chwnd = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($chwnd, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
   curl_setopt($chwnd, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_setopt($chwnd, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($chwnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, TRUE);
   $returned = curl_exec($chwnd);
   curl_close ($chwnd);
   // /search?where=bhm&start_with=1&search_loc_type=9&x=0&y=0
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well - if this is your final query `search?where=phx&start_with=1&search_loc_type=9&x=5&y=13` so just assemble it as you like:

```
//take the paremeter: (using post ?! )
$Airport_variable = $_POST['where'];

$url = "http://www.weather.com/activities/travel/businesstraveler/";
//quertstring:
$url .= 'search?where=' . $Airport_variable . '&start_with=1&search_loc_type=9&x=5&y=13';

$chwnd = curl_init();
curl_setopt($chwnd, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
.
.
.
```

Comment: Can you explain how that works? Would this be after my first curled page?  To answer your question this is GET request.  When i search a airport code on my current page it says request url not found im trying to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: You should write a function of course for it - it takes as parameter the where param and generate a curl request with that param if it's given and if not the regular curl - so you don't write the same code twice...

Comment: There is also two ways i can do this.  I can use the search form or the option menus and select city and then airport using this referral link http://localhost/outlook/travel/airportprofile/MLI  

Where  http://localhost/outlook/travel/airportprofile/ . $Airport_variable  What would be easier option?  Would i save this the same way creating a function or can i use a built in curl keyword to curl the second page search query.

Comment: I read it twice and did not understand sorry - what again are you trying to do ?

Comment: There are two ways i can approach this problem.  I can either use the search query string that i first posted about or i can use the drop down menus that select a city and based on that select it shows airports.  When a user selects airport he or she is redirected to this page.   localhost/outlook/travel/airportprofile/MLI  or from the website http://www.weather.com/outlook/travel/businesstraveler/airportprofile/ANC . which would display the weather based on airport code.

Comment: Would it be easier to use the drop down menu and add the airport code on to this url, for example

http://www.weather.com/outlook/travel/businesstraveler/airportprofile/.$Airport_variable or is the previous way easier?  Not sure how to implement this.

Comment: use select will be easier on the end-user so I think this is better - but both ways are legit - the question is what is best for your intentions

Comment: Both options would work, but i am leaning more towards the select option.  I am just wondering which way would be easier to implement.  My current code works with the drop downs, but once a user selects the second drop down the page displays "object is not found".  I am trying to fix this error and curl that second page.

Comment: both way it will be none issue - meaning easy in both of them

Comment: Can you give me idea what i need to code to fix the request page after the second option is selected?